# My website redirects to another website on google searches

Tags: google-search, hacking

I'm not sure if my website has been hacked or what have happened.

When I do some searches on google in which my website should show up, my website with a different url name does. It maintains the title that appears on google after doing the search and the description of it.

Moreover, when looking for "mywebsite" without "www." and ".com" on google, my website shows up the first one but in 4th position the random website which sells glasses does, again having the title and description I have for my website.

I don't know what to do. Already contacted with google analytics and checked .htaccess. If someone knows something related to this i'd apreaciate any help.

Comment: Sorry but as it stands answers would be guessing to say the least. Please include details such as htaccess files, vhost setup, header responses, additionally sharing the site URL in question really helps.

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30843296/1591669) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what has happened here is that the other website has stolen your website's content, and passing it off as it's own. If you do a `ping` request on that website's URL it's IP address is should be different to your own website's IP address.

I would message Google via Google Webmaster Tools and inform them of the other website and they will act accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. It seems google is working on it as some of the searches done in google are functionally right now and others aren't still but I hope they will.

Comment: It'll take some time, as they'll have notified (or at least tried) the owner of the other site. It's annoying, but take it as a compliment that you're doing something so right on your own site other people feel the need to steal your sites content and/or your traffic

Comment: I'd also post in Google's webmaster help forum with the URL & query, so people can take a look at your specific case. Sometimes these are from subtile hacks that are really tricky to spot, and sometimes they need to be escalated to a Googler to review.